# Article with an appositive phrase

Tags: articles, appositives

Please help me understand whether I need an article and why.

*"Companies I have worked with:

- Wolfestone, translation agency (Swansea, UK)
- [...]"*

Do I have to place an article before "translation agency"? I feel that if it were in a sentence, I would need an article, but in a list like that (it's from my CV) I'd better omit it. Is this feeling right or wrong? Are there any rules for such situations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using 'a' here would look amateurish. Deletions often occur in headlines, titles, comments on ELU ....

Comment: I disagree with the previous comment. The lack of an article looks amateurish to me—given the explanatory *translation agency*. An alternative would be ***The*** *translation agency Wolfstone (Swansea, UK)*.